Expectation over cost-normalized Expected improvements
Are the following two expressions equivalent if we assume the independence of f(x) and C(x)?
$$
E\left[\frac{E\left[\max\left(f(x) - f(x^*), 0\right)\right]} {C(x)}\right] 
$$
$$
\frac{E\left[\max\left(f(x) - f(x^*), 0\right)\right]}  {E\left[C(x)\right]}
$$
Where
f(x) and C(x) are objective and cost functions respectively, $f(x^*)$ is the best recorded objective from previous iterations.

probably useful https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/expectation-of-ratio-of-2-independent-random-variables.735073/
